# How can I launch my API locally and call endpoints from a single powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I need my PowerShell script to launch my API locally and then call a swagger endpoint.

I've figured out how to call the API:

```
Invoke-Expression "dotnet run 'MyApi.csproj' --no-build --launch-profile 'RUNLOCAL'"
```

That works, and I can load the swagger endpoint from my browser. But I want the script to load it.

I need to launch the API and execute the following immediately after:

```
# wait for the api to finish launching before doing anything
while (!(Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 5001).TcpTestSucceeded) { Start-Sleep 1 }

# execute the next command
openapi-generator-cli.cmd generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

So it seems I need to launch the API in the background

I do this by executing:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    "dotnet run"    
    'MyApi.csproj'
    "--no-build"
    "--launch-profile 'RUNLOCAL'"
  }

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

When I do this I see the output:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
489    Job489          BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

This suggests that the command worked, but I can't access my API anymore either from the Browser or subsequent commands in the script. The command to wait for the API to finish launching never returns true so the API isn't running or is not accessible.

**Question**
What can I do to make this work? Do I need to launch the API in the background and if so how can I do that and continue to use it in the script?

For reference, this is the complete script:

```
$mypath = Get-Location

$ScriptBlock = {
    "dotnet run"    
    'MyApi.csproj'
    "--no-build"
    "--launch-profile 'RUNLOCAL'"
  }

cd "..\..\Path\To\Project.csproj"

#presumably launches api in the background
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

cd $mypath

#presumably return true when api is launched and continue execution
while (!(Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 5001).TcpTestSucceeded) { Start-Sleep 1 }

openapi-generator-cli.cmd generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

Comment: `"dotnet run"` is just a string. change your job to `dotnet run 'MyApi.csproj' --no-build --launch-profile 'RUNLOCAL'` without double-quotes

Comment: that didn't quite work. It does the same as before, and actually gives me the same output no matter what I change any of it to. Is there a way to invoke a command with the scriptblock so I can see what the actual output is, and then when that works change it to Start-Job?

Comment: If you want to execute a scriptblock in the current session rather than as a background job you can call ```$scriptblock.Invoke()```, but note that per @SantiagoSquarzon, all your scriptblock is doing at the moment is returning some strings, rather than executing a command.

Comment: The issue is you are running script in background when you do not need to run in background.  Once it is running in background you can't access the process a second time.  You just need to invoke and wait until the process finishes.